# Ways of populating n boxes (placed in a row) with items such that no two consecutive boxes have items

Tags: combinatorics

So if I have `n` boxes in a row, and wanted to populate it with items (total no of items>=0) such that no two boxes in a row have items, how many ways can it be done?

I was trying to derive some closed form solution for this, but got nowhere.

Comment: Break into cases based on number of boxes which will be non-empty.  Pick which boxes those are and apply stars and bars.  Sum over all cases.

Comment: @JMoravitz So maximum number of nonempty boxes is n/2. And for a given number of nonempty boxes (m), the number of ways to fill the n boxes with m items is (n-m+1)C(m). So I need summation of (n-m+1)C(m) from 0 to n/2. Am I right?

Comment: @IndoUbt  Number of non-empty boxes can go up to $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ for odd $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We break into cases based on how many boxes are non-empty.  Call this amount $m$.  We notice that $0\leq m\leq \lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$.

Next, choose which $m$ boxes specifically are the non-empty ones.  To do this, break into cases on whether the furthest right box is empty or non-empty.  With the furthest right box empty, take every non-empty box and glue an empty box to its right.  We have then $m$ non-empty-next-to-empty boxes and $n-2m$ empty boxes to arrange.  There are $\binom{n-m}{m}$ ways to do this.  In the case that the furthest right box is non-empty, by looking at the first $n-1$ boxes instead we are in the same case as before, giving $\binom{(n-1)-(2(m-1))+(m-1)}{m-1}=\binom{n-m}{m-1}$.  This gives a total of $\binom{n-m}{m}+\binom{n-m}{m-1}=\binom{n-m+1}{m}$ ways to select which are the non-empty boxes.

Now, given $m$ non-empty boxes, we wish to distribute $k$ items among them such that every non-empty box receives at least one item.  By stars and bars this is $\binom{k-1}{m-1}$

We get then as a final total:

$$\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil} \binom{n-m+1}{m}\binom{k-1}{m-1}$$